# Implementing all methods of an interface

Tags: interface

When working with hashmap or any other collection we don't necessarily implement all the methods available in the implemented interface we only implement the ones we need how is this possible yet when implementing an interface we have to implement all it's methods

Answer (score 0):

If a class implements an interface, you have to implement all of the methods. If there are really methods you don't want to or can't implement, I'd recommend throwing a NotImplementedException for that methods.